# Can't send user data if firebaseAuth.signOut() si called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am a bit confused about why this is happening.

I want to update my user profile in the Registration Activity, it all works fine and the database is updated, until I add firebaseAuth.signOut() to the sendUserData() function. Does anyone have this problem before?

```java
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText userName, userPassword, userEmail, phoneNumber;
    private Button logButton, regButton;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    String email, name, phone, password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        setupUIViews();

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        regButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(validate()){
                    //upload everithing to the database
                    String user_name = userName.getText().toString().trim();
                    String user_email = userEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                    String user_password = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                    String user_phone = phoneNumber.getText().toString().trim();

                    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email, user_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                sendEmailVerification();
                            }
                            else{
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        });
        logButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupUIViews(){
        userName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUser2);
        userPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPas2);
        userEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail2);
        phoneNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPhone1);
        regButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registerButton2);
        logButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButton2);

    }

    private Boolean validate(){
        Boolean result = false;

         name = userName.getText().toString();
         email = userEmail.getText().toString();
         phone = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
         password = userPassword.getText().toString();

        if(name.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty()){
           Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter all the details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void sendEmailVerification(){
        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if(firebaseUser != null){
            firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        sendUserData();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Sucessfully registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 //---------------->>>//firebaseAuth.signOut();//<<<-----------//
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Verification email was not sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void sendUserData(){
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
        UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile(name, email, phone);

        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User data was sent to the database" + firebaseDatabase.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        myRef.setValue(userProfile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                firebaseAuth.signOut();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So the database works (data is uploaded into the real-time database by firebase) without the logout, but then I have the problem that the user is automatically logged in in the UserProfileActivity.

Comment: What is your database security rules? If you have something like `allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null` it won't let you as of your auth is signed off so this rule restricts it. Do you have any logcat messages saying something like permission denied?

Comment: Those are my rulles {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth!= null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}

Comment: If you have your sign off in the onSuccess listener in your `sendUserData()` it does not work either? Try to put it in onComplete listener instead

Comment: Why do you want to sign out the user straight after creating that user?

Comment: So that he's not automatically logged in without validating his email

Answer (score 0):

Please provide error trace or error so that we can understand what's happening.and btw,your toast should be displayed inside onSuccessListener().You are displaying toast before it is checking whether the task is sucess or not